# How to locate google search bar by id with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, web

I'm learning selenium with python and I keep getting the following error when trying to do a google search: "Unable to locate element: [id="lst-ib"]"

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")


search_field = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
search_field.clear()
search_field.send_keys("argentina vnl 2019")
search_field.submit()
```

Answer (score 1):

- Search by input name

**Note:** Google no longer support id field in search input element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get("https://google.com")
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("argentina vnl 2019")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(4)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: this is using name, not id

Comment: @Corey Goldberg. I agree with you but we can achieve same thing in different ways, it's that.

Comment: Thanks this works. But I'm still curious about why it doesn't work using id

Comment: @bharatk of course you can achieve the same result in different ways.  Your answer might even be a helpful workaround to the OP...   but it doesn't answer the question that was asked... that was specifically about locating by id.

Comment: @Xcecution Search input element has not id field. see google search input element code.`<input class="gLFyf gsfi" maxlength="2048" name="q" type="text" jsaction="paste:puy29d" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="false" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" role="combobox" spellcheck="false" title="Search" value="" aria-label="Search" data-ved="0ahUKEwiSwMnpgqfjAhVIL48KHQ1bB2EQ39UDCAQ">`
So basically you can get element object **by xpath**, **by name**  or **by class**.

Comment: so that should have been your answer

Comment: Yes, adding that it is not possible to do a search by `id`, *then* indicating a work around, would be a more compete, and ultimately useful, answer. Please `edit` your answer to include the info from your comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Google has changed this. `id` is not present anymore. There is no longer any way to search by input `id`.